# How to uncap dishwasher water lines?

Tags: pipe, dishwasher

I moved into a mobile home that has the spaces and water lines for a dishwasher but the landlord says I would have to have a plumber uncap the lines... can’t really afford the plumber. Can I do this myself?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture of the capped lines would probably help.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use push to connect fittings like [sharkbite](https://www.sharkbite.com) fittings. Some tools will still be required. If copper pipe is present then you need a copper cutter like the [Ridged 118](https://store.ridgid.com/us/en/parts/86127#6572), if it's pex you need a [PEX cutter](https://www.supplyhouse.com/PEX-Cutters-563000). You can pick up all these tools at Home Depot and the like. You'll probably want to get a pair of [Channellock pliers](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/809496942253020049?lsf=seller:6169538,store:10651940791067250909&prds=oid:77755574289959727&q=channellock%20pliers&hl=en&ei=dsmeXNK4OIHmsAWXlLCYDQ&lsft=gclid:Cj0KCQjwhPfkBRD0ARIsAAcYycErGuLQR9k8uFeXWpsfMtq5WhznOwoDFBlPNbznFZiZCtuZH9cH0fcaAndIEALw_wcB,gclsrc:aw.ds) or splurge and get the [Knipex Cobra](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.amazon.ca/Knipex-8701250-10-Inch-Cobra-Pliers/dp/B000X4J2H0&ved=2ahUKEwjSsZ7R3qjhAhUEXK0KHfIwATEQFjAFegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw33kMd0keyKVnV5lUbT44LU) pliers. You'll possibly need some electrical tools and need to do some drain work.

Make sure to turn the power off and the water. If you don't already own some of these basic tools it may be more expensive to buy them than to call a plumber, unless you can borrow some.

Push conections work on both copper and PEX and you may find a push to connect adapter with the dishwasher end ready to go. I do believe they sell a dishwasher kit that has much of the required material.